# XML binding to DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, datagrid, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to bind XML data to DataView. I'm following [this guide](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mamta_m/binding-xml-to-a-wpf-datagrid/) however even though I can see the result under Visual Studio 2013, I cannot see the result when I run the program. I tried adding Movies.xml to Resources and adding it to project directory. Currently it resides under project root path. While I was writing this post, for a while I saw the result while project is running, however after clean build it disappeared again.

Movies.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Movies xmlns="">
  <Movie Name="Seven Samurai" Id="101" Director="Akira Kurosawa" />
  <Movie Name="Happy Together" Id="102" Director="Wong Kar Wai"/>
  <Movie Name="Shoot The Piano Player" Id="103" Director="Francois Truffaut"/>
  <Movie Name="Roshomon" Id="104" Director="Akira Kurosawa" />
  <Movie Name="Dead Man" Id="105" Director="Jim Jarmusch"/>
  <Movie Name="Children of Heaven" Id="106" Director="Majid Majidi"/>
</Movies>
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridXML.MainWindow"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <XmlDataProvider x:Key="MovieData" Source="Movies.xml" XPath="/Movies/Movie"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgridEmp" DataContext="{StaticResource MovieData}" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/Movies/Movie}"
 AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="52,89,31,50">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Name}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Director}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Visual Studio Preview:
[image: Visual Studio Preview]

Project run-time:

[image: Run time]

My final goal is to bind such XML dynamically, so that user will choose which XML to parse. Then user can change the content and save.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this, first convert your xml to a `DataSet` then simply set your `DataGrid`'s `ItemsSource` to `DataView`:

```
string sampleXmlFile = @"C:\Users\umut.koseali\Desktop\test.xml";
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(sampleXmlFile);
DataView dataView = new DataView(dataSet.Tables[0]);
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dataView
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure, that you marked the "Movies.xml" as Content in the IDE?

[image: Sample]

You could read more from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Medeni, thanks for pointing out that embedded files should be marked as Content. However my final goal is to use any XML file that user points.